# How to get refference on object on reccursion?

Tags: android, recursion

I am starting asynctask from activity. Sometimes SearchAdd does not returns desired result ( due to TimeOuts etc) So, i call it recursivly up to 5 times. But I messed up, how to update refenece to SearchAdd in activity after selfcall.

```
SearchAdd s = new SearchAdd(callback);
                s.execute();
```

Asyntask

```
    public class SearchAdd extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

        private SearchAddInterface callback;
        private int trial = 0;

        public SearchAdd(SearchAddInterface callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }

        public SearchAdd(SearchAddInterface callback, int trial) {
            this.callback = callback;
            this.trial = trial;
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            return JSONParser.getJSONfromURL(RequestStringCreater
                    .concatenationStrings().replaceAll("\\s", "%20"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result == null){
                if(trial <5){
                SearchAdd sAdd = new SearchAdd(callback, trial);}
}

        }else{
            // do job
            }

        }
```

Comment: can you not rearchitect this to avoid the recursion? it will make thigns easier to debug.

Comment: Are you meaning to show full code or change it to work without recursion? The onl problem which i have - I cannot call .cancel() which i need.

Comment: can you explain it little more what you are actually look for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1335855/bharat-sharma, I want to call s.cancel() to stop the SearchAdd asynctask. But i cannot cancell it, if  doInBackground returned null and SearchAdd created new instance of itselff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the recursion and allow the request to be cancelled, you can do this:

```
public class SearchAdd extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

    private SearchAddInterface callback;
    private int trial = 0;
    private boolean cancel = false;

    public SearchAdd(SearchAddInterface callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void cancel() {
        cancel = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        JSONObject result = null;
        while (!cancel && (trial < 5) && (result == null)) {
            trial++;
            result = JSONParser.getJSONfromURL(RequestStringCreater.concatenationStrings().replaceAll("\\s", "%20"));
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (cancel) {
            // The request was cancelled
        } else if (result == null) {
            // All trials have failed.
        } else {
            // Do job
        }
    }
}
```